# Converting the date format in R

Tags: r, date

I try to do the date format conversion in R and I encounter the following problem: my original date is

```
"Dec-2011"
```

I want is becomes

```
2011-12
```

Then I tried

```
as.Date("Dec-2011",format = "%b-%Y")
```

It produces NA

I did some search, and I found that if you type

```
as.Date(gsub("^", "01-", "Dec-2011"), format="%d-%b-%Y")
```

It will give you

```
2011-12-01
```

I understand the function "gsub" does here, which is replace all the "^" in the "Dec-2011" by "01-". However, as you can see in "Dec-2011", there is no "^" and I am thinking whether it should be "01-" or "-01"? I am a little puzzled. What does the "gsub" really do here? And how should I perform date format conversion in R?

Comment: `paste` will be more easier. `paste0("01-", "Dec-2011")`

Comment: @akrun thanks, this works. One step further, I am looking at the whole column which contains "Dec-2011", "May-2008" stuff like that. I feel that as.Date(gsub("^", "01-", "Dec-2011"), format="%d-%b-%Y") this command works pretty well, but I really cannot figure out why it works, e.g., I didn't see "^" in "Dec-2011" but it seems that this gsub function still does the correct thing. Do you have an idea about how it works?

Comment: The `"yearmon"` class can repesent a year/month object without a day.  Such objects sort correctly and do not need to be associated with an arbitrary day of the month such as the first or last.  `library(zoo); as.yearmon("Dec-2011", format = "%b-%Y")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `^` is a metacharacter to represent the start of a string.  In the `gsub` example, the `pattern` gives the position for the `replacement` ("01-"), thus it replaces only at the start.  Suppose, if we remove the `^`, it will replace the "01-" after every character

```
gsub("", "01-", "Dec-2011")
#[1] "01-D01-e01-c01--01-201-001-101-101-"

gsub("^", "01-", "Dec-2011")
#[1] "01-Dec-2011"
```

`gsub` means global substitution, but we can replace it once with `sub` too

```
sub("", "01-", "Dec-2011")
#[1] "01-Dec-2011"
```

---

For this case, it may be easier to use `paste`

```
paste0("01-", "Dec-2011")
#[1] "01-Dec-2011"
```